# How do you get the position of the side of a block so you can place a block perfectly next to the block

Tags: lua, roblox

A example, image two blocks,

**Part1** and **Part2**, Part1 is placed in the game as a normal block, while Part2 is placed into the game using a script, then before it gets placed into the workspace, the script gets the side position of Part1 then puts Part2 position as the side of Part1 afterwards then placing it into workspace.

So then Part2 will be perfectly next to Part1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean simple Parts with no CSG operations on them, you can do some simple math to line them up.

Try something like this :

```
local function createRandomBlock(name, brickColor)
    -- create a randomly sized block
    local part = Instance.new("Part")
    part.Name = name
    part.Size = Vector3.new(math.random(1,10), math.random(1,10), math.random(1,10))
    part.BrickColor = brickColor
    part.Anchored = true
    part.CanCollide = false
    part.Transparency = 0.5
    part.Parent = game.Workspace
    part.BottomSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Smooth
    part.TopSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Smooth

    return part
end

-- place part 1 floating in the air, rotated randomly
local twoPi = 2 * math.pi
local testCFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0,10,0))
testCFrame = testCFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.random(0,twoPi), math.random(0,twoPi), math.random(0,twoPi))

local testBlock = createRandomBlock("Test", BrickColor.White())
testBlock.CFrame = testCFrame

-- start placing blocks relative to the test block
local pFront = createRandomBlock("Front", BrickColor.Red())
pFront.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (testBlock.CFrame.LookVector * (testBlock.Size.Z + pFront.Size.Z) * 0.5)

local pBack = createRandomBlock("Back", BrickColor.Red())
pBack.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (-1 * testBlock.CFrame.LookVector * (testBlock.Size.Z + pBack.Size.Z) * 0.5)

local pRight = createRandomBlock("Right", BrickColor.Blue())
pRight.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (testBlock.CFrame.RightVector * (testBlock.Size.X + pRight.Size.X) * 0.5)

local pLeft = createRandomBlock("Left", BrickColor.Blue())
pLeft.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (-1 * testBlock.CFrame.RightVector * (testBlock.Size.X + pLeft.Size.X) * 0.5)

local pTop = createRandomBlock("Top", BrickColor.Green())
pTop.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (testBlock.CFrame.UpVector * (testBlock.Size.Y + pTop.Size.Y) * 0.5)

local pBottom = createRandomBlock("Bottom", BrickColor.Green())
pBottom.CFrame = testBlock.CFrame + (-1 * testBlock.CFrame.UpVector * (testBlock.Size.Y + pBottom.Size.Y) * 0.5)
```

This example places a block at the origin and orients it randomly. Then it adds parts and sticks them to the sides of the test block.